# merging data frames without deleting unique values (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what seems like a simple problem but I can figure out how to do it...

I have 3 Dataframes.

```
df1 : 1 column, Product SKU

df2 : 2 Columns, Product SKU, Price(supplier 1)

df3 : 2 Columns, Product SKU, Price( Supplier 2)
```

I need to create a df4.

```
df4 : 3 Columns, Product SKU, Supplier 1 Price, Supplier 2 Price
```

Supplier 1 and 2 have some matching `SKU`.

`df4` needs to contain all `SKU`'s, and the price from each supplier. When the Supplier doesn't have a price for that `SKU` it should be `0` or `Nan`.

Any help will be great, I've tried `merge()`, `join()`, `concatenate()` and dropping duplicates but can't achieve the result I am looking for.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

USE - `df4 = df2.merge(df3, on="Product_SKU", how = 'outer')`

Code-

I Created random dataframe `df4` it contains all unique `Product_SKU` and some rows will contain `NaN` values as it's price is not present in `df2` or `df3`.

```
# initialize list of lists
data2 = [['clutch', 10], ['brake', 15],['tyre',50]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Product_SKU', 'Price_Supplier_1'])

# initialize list of lists
data3 = [['tyre', 30], ['brake', 25],['gear',100]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['Product_SKU', 'Price_Supplier_2'])
  
df4 = df2.merge(df3, on="Product_SKU", how = 'outer')
df4
```

Output-

```
Product_SKU Price_Supplier_1    Price_Supplier_2
0   clutch       10.0              NaN
1   brake        15.0              25.0
2   tyre         50.0              30.0
3   gear         NaN               100.0
```